# Rake spec not running with upgraded ruby

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rake, specifications

I'm fairly new to ruby, and the company I work for has us do local spec tests for our code before checking it in. Up until a few days ago, my spec tests were running completely fine, but I recently upgraded from the default OS X ruby version (1.8.7) to 2.0.0, and 'rake spec' now fails with the output below, I've abbreviated to the relevant information:

```
/Users/Jordan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-puppet-0.1.5/lib/rspec-puppet.rb:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- puppet (LoadError)
from /Users/Jordan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-puppet-0.1.5/lib/rspec-puppet.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Jordan/edmunds_dev/spec/spec_helper.rb:1:in `require'
from /Users/Jordan/edmunds_dev/spec/spec_helper.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Jordan/edmunds_dev/modules/apache/spec/classes/apache_spec.rb:1:in `require'
from /Users/Jordan/edmunds_dev/modules/apache/spec/classes/apache_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Jordan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load'
from /Users/Jordan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `block in load_spec_files'
from /Users/Jordan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `map'
from /Users/Jordan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core- 2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load_spec_files'
from /Users/Jordan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-  2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
from /Users/Jordan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
from /Users/Jordan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:8:in `block in autorun'
rake aborted!
/Users/Jordan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby -S rspec
```

**What I tried:**

reinstalling ruby, and all relevant gems

Updating rubygems, then reinstalling relevant gems

Looking at the Rakefile

**What I'm about to do:**

Reinstall my OS or just go ballistic deleting everything that has ruby in the name and reinstall it.

Comment: Do you use Bundler?  Or some other gem manager?

Comment: Yes, I am currently using bundler.

Comment: Ok, good to know.  Check my answer thread for more details re: bundler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `puppet` is not installed for ruby 2.0.x yet.  You probably had it installed for 1.8.7.  All gems need to be installed against the latest ruby version.

If using Bundler, ensure that `puppet` is in your Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'puppet'

# Once the issue is ironed out, place this and other spec-related
# gems in the test group
gem 'rspec-puppet'
```

Then, ensure bundler loads the environment via `bundle exec rake spec`.

Or install it manually, using:

```
gem install puppet
```

Check out [the rspec-puppet documentation](http://rspec-puppet.com/) for additional details.

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned I tried doing this, unfortunately after running `gem install puppet` It comes up with
/Users/Jordan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'puppet' (>= 0) among 35 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
 from /Users/Jordan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
 from /Users/Jordan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
 from /Users/Jordan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/puppet:22:in `<main>'

Comment: Ok, run `bundle list` to see what gems bundler is loading.  Assuming `puppet` is there, run `bundle exec rake spec`.  If `puppet` is not there, add it to the Gemfile and run `bundle`.

Comment: Ok, I got most of everything fixed by removing `Gemfile.lock` and then running `bundle install` again.

Comment: Yeah, that's one way to clean up the `Gemfile.lock` =)  In the future, you can also run `bundle update` and it will resolve all dependencies and then update all the gems to the latest versions that satisfy those dependencies.  I suspect `bundle install` with no lockfile does something similar.

Comment: After that, I deleted everything ruby-related on my system, and a line from my bash_profile (rvm likes to hook into that), and reinstalled puppet as a gem. Now works flawlessley. Thanks!